# Interchange integral and limit in $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \int \frac{(f(x+z) - f(z))^2}{x^2 f(z)} dz$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am looking for simple conditions on a probability density function $f$ such that the limit and integral can be exchanged in the following expression:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \int \frac{(f(x+z) - f(z))^2}{x^2 f(z)} dz = \int \frac{(f'(z))^2}{f(z)} dz. $$

I'd like to use the median value theorem and apply dominated convergence, but that doesn't seem sufficient. E.g., assume $f'(z)/f(z)$ is polynomially bounded and $f(z)$ has finite moments. After applying the median value theorem, one has $f'(\theta_z + z)^2/f(z)$ which may not be integrable. Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is the domain of integration of $z$?

Comment: Say $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ has full support.